# Batch Program IF THEN help needed

Tags: loops, batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

I have an XML file to read, and certain nodes I already have parsed.  Here is an example:

```
 <goingTo>RNS</goingTo>
 <goingTo>HTY</goingTo>
```

The cmd code to extract from the XML file looks like this:

```
 for /F "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%i in ('findstr "<goingTo>" AST.xml') do echo %%i >>To_Places.txt
```

This all works fine, with a result of:

```
RNS
HTY
```

in my `To_Places.txt` file.

Also in my XML I am trying to parse and add conditional statements, but I am having a hard time with that.

In my XML file I have to iterate through the file to check if something is loaded or empty.

A snippet of the node in XML:

```
 <VehWeight>14.878</VehWeight>
 <VehWeight>4.98</VeWeight>
```

I need the batch code to look through the XML file, read the `VehWeight` data and execute `GTR 14 = Load` or `LSS 14 = MTY`. Then have this output to a text file appended to the `To_Places.txt` file.

Is there such a way in batch?

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but any attempt to do this is likely to be fragile and error-prone.  I'd suggest you use a scripting language that supports parsing XML (e.g. VBScript, PowerShell), which you can call from a batch file if that's what you want.

Comment: I don't tend to agree to most "do not use batch" comments, but @Joe is right here. XML files tend to not have proper line endings, what makes it nearly impossible to handle them with batch. Although it seems that your source _has_ proper line endings, future versions might _not_ have them.

Answer (score 1):

When reading or manipulating XML, it's always better to treat it *as* structured XML, rather than trying to hack and scrape it as text with token delimiters or regular expressions.  That way, regardless of whether the XML is beautified or uglified, it still works.

I like to use JScript for this sort of thing.  It's very easy to include as hybrid code in a .bat file, and it handles document object model navigation easily (just as JavaScript does).

Save this with a .bat extension and run it.  See whether it gives you the results you expect.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

set "XMLfile=AST.xml"
set "outfile=To_Places.txt"

cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%XMLfile%" "%outfile%" && echo Done.

goto :EOF
@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

var fso = WSH.CreateObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'),
    DOM = WSH.CreateObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM'),
    args = { xmlfile: WSH.Arguments(0), outfile: WSH.Arguments(1) };

DOM.load(args.xmlfile);
DOM.async = false;
DOM.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');

if (DOM.parseError.errorCode) {
    var e = DOM.parseError;
    WSH.StdErr.WriteLine('Error in ' + args.xmlfile + ' line ' + e.line + ' char '
        + e.linepos + ':\n' + e.reason + '\n' + e.srcText);
    WSH.Quit(1);
}

var out = fso.CreateTextFile(args.outfile, 1);

for (var d = DOM.selectNodes('//goingTo/text()'), i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
    out.WriteLine(d[i].nodeValue);

for (var d = DOM.selectNodes('//VehWeight/text()'), i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
    out.WriteLine(d[i].nodeValue * 1 < 14 ? 'MTY' : 'LOAD');

out.Close();
```